# PHP: why is unix gmt time an hour fast?

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

if I set my timezone to GMT and use the PHP date() function to get the current time/date stamp it gets the correct time. however when I used a unix generator to make a timestamp for 9am this morning it comes back as 10am even though I've used various different generators and made sure they are in GMT. why is it coming back an hour fast? here is my code:

```
<?php
     date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
     $timestamp_time = date("hi", 1377766800);
     echo $timestamp_time;
?>
```

Comment: DST/Daylight Saving Time

Comment: ah ok that would do it... how do I account for this?

Comment: The unix_timestamp should be the same regardless of timezone or DST. How are you generating it?

Comment: http://www.timestampgenerator.com/

Comment: what "generators" are you using? When entering your TS at http://www.unixtimestamp.com/ it returns "08 / 29 / 13 @ 4:00:00am EST" and EST is GMT - 5 (+DST when appropriate). Is Daylight Saving Time biting you? Id always go with UTC.

Comment: so even though I use timestampgenerator.com and set it to GMT it doesn't give me the correct time?

Comment: This still isn't solved, I must use GMT not UTC or EST. How do I allow for daylight savings?

Comment: Do I just use an if statement to say, if winter months -1 hour and if summer months +1 hour?